# Exclude OU in a powershell script

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have the following script:

```
#Script uses quest powershell commandlets which can be downloaded for free from quest website 
# http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx 

#Specify the OU you want to search for inactive accounts 

    $SearchOU=“OU=Sites,DC=nl,DC=example,DC=com" 

#Specify the OU you want to move your inactive computer accounts to 

    #$DestinationOU=“CN=Computers,DC=**,DC=example,DC=com" 

#Specify the number of days that computers have been inactive for 

    $NumOfDaysInactiveFor = 100 

#Specify the description to set on the computer account 

    $Today = Get-Date 

    $Description = "Account disabled due to inactivity on $Today" 

Get-QADComputer -InactiveFor $NumOfDaysInactiveFor -SizeLimit 0 -SearchRoot $searchOU -IncludedProperties ParentContainerDN | foreach {  

    $computer = $_.ComputerName 
    $SourceOU = $_.DN 

    #Remove the commented # from the next line if you want to set the description to be the source OU 
    #$Description = "SourceOU was $SourceOu" 

    Set-QADComputer $computer -Description $Description 

    Disable-QADComputer $computer 

    #Move-QADObject $computer -NewParentContainer $destinationOU  



}
```

What I want to do is exclude one or multiple OUs that are in the SearchOU, is this possible? I have no idea how I can manage this.

I use the following `SearchOU = OU=Sites,DC=nl,DC=example,DC=com`. I want to exclude the following OU for example `= OU=Warehouses,OU=*,OU=Sites,DC=*,DC=example,DC=com`

Answer (score 0):

With the `-LdapFilter`  option you can set a case-sensitive LDAP search filter. But AFAIK  filtering on DN's with for instance an `(!ou=WareHouses)` is not supported...

The typical approach  would  be a nested loop that first, with a search scope of one level, lists the OU's and then performs your intended search in all OU's whose names don't match `*,ou=WareHouses,*`

In pseudo code:

```
for COUNTRY in DC=*.DC=example,DC=com
  do 
    for OrgUnit in OU=*,DC=$COUNTRY,DC=example,DC=com 
      do
        if ( $OrgUnit != *WareHouses* ) {
           Get-QADComputer -SearchRoot $OrgUnit .... 
        }
    done
done
```

Comment: I don't get it, this script is not mine I found it on the internet so my powershell skills are minimum.

Comment: In short the answer to your question is: No you can **not** create a single LDAP query that excludes results from a specific OU. AD does not provide that facility. - The normal option to restrict the result set is called an *"LDAP filter"* but the is no filter that allows for that. - Powershell is a very useful for a (Windows) sysadmin and you would do well to develop some skills in writing PowerShell scripts beyond copying them from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more detailed response to HBruijn.  I added a line to the code below filtering out the 'Warehouses' OUs you specified.  This can be edited to have multiple OUs or adjust the regex expression to fit your needs.  Thee are so many ways to do this.

```
#Specify the OU you want to search for inactive accounts 

$SearchOU=“OU=Sites,DC=nl,DC=example,DC=com" 

#Specify the OU you want to move your inactive computer accounts to 

#$DestinationOU=“CN=Computers,DC=**,DC=example,DC=com" 

#Specify the number of days that computers have been inactive for 

$NumOfDaysInactiveFor = 100 

#Specify the description to set on the computer account 

$Today = Get-Date 

$Description = "Account disabled due to inactivity on $Today" 

Get-QADComputer -InactiveFor $NumOfDaysInactiveFor -SizeLimit 0 -SearchRoot $searchOU -IncludedProperties ParentContainerDN | foreach {  

#Filter out OUs we don't care about

if ( $_.DN -notmatch 'OU=Warehouses,OU=.*,OU=Sites,DC=.*,DC=example,DC=com') {

    $computer = $_.ComputerName 
    $SourceOU = $_.DN 

    #Remove the commented # from the next line if you want to set the description to be the source OU 
    #$Description = "SourceOU was $SourceOu" 

    Set-QADComputer $computer -Description $Description 

    Disable-QADComputer $computer 

    #Move-QADObject $computer -NewParentContainer $destinationOU  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quest AD cmdlets were useful... once upon a time.

But now you can simply `import-module ActiveDirectory`.

And then get a list of AD users (or computers, or whatever) and filter out the ones contained in a specific OU:

```
$searchou = 'OU=MyOU,DC=domain,DC=com'  
$excludeou = "ouname'

Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase $searchou  | where { $_.DistinguishedName
 -notlike $ouname }
```